# Parsing specific data items from website

Tags: php, parsing, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I tried to retrieve the following data variables from the [***this webpage***](http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_details_short.do?rx_dest=/index.gsp&rx_title=com.wm.www.apps.storelocator.page.serviceLink.title.default&edit_object_id=2092&sfsearch_single_line_address=K6T)

- Address
- City
- State
- Zip Code
- Store Phone
- Pharmacy Phone
- Open Hours
- Pharmacy Hours
- Pickup Options
- At this store/location
- Site to Store Hours

I tried in this way, but i can't separate out some data to store in the above data variables so need some help and suggestion from some PHP expert

```
 $html = file_get_html('http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_results.do?serviceName=&rx_title=com.wm.www.apps.storelocator.page.serviceLink.title.default&rx_dest=%2Findex.gsp&sfrecords=50&sfsearch_single_line_address=K6T');
foreach($html->find('div[class=StoreAddress] div[1]') as $name)
{
echo $name->innertext.'<br>';
}
```

The html of this website is complex to identify each data item with it's tag because their are no proper id assigned to tags.  Can anyone please suggest easy and scalable way  to parse above data items from this [website](http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_details_short.do?rx_dest=/index.gsp&rx_title=com.wm.www.apps.storelocator.page.serviceLink.title.default&edit_object_id=2092&sfsearch_single_line_address=K6T).

Thanks

Comment: Actually the problem is that many tags have same class name, or some tags don't have any id or class to identify..
So some unwanted data is also parsed... 

I am confused about which data to store in which variable because all have same tags,class, and no id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html isn't really that complex. Php's iterators and dom/regex functions are clumsy for tasks like this but it can be done:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_details_short.do?rx_dest=/index.gsp&rx_title=com.wm.www.apps.storelocator.page.serviceLink.title.default&edit_object_id=2092&sfsearch_single_line_address=K6T');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//div[@class="StoreAddress"]') as $div) {
  // title
  echo $xpath->query(".//div[1]", $div)->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
  // street
  echo $xpath->query(".//div[2]", $div)->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n";
  // city state and zip
  preg_match('/(.*), ([A-Z]{2}) (\d{5})/', $xpath->query(".//div[3]", $div)->item(0)->nodeValue, $m);
  // city
  echo $m[1] . "\n";
  // state
  echo $m[2] . "\n";
  // zip
  echo $m[3] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks pguardiario!!
but I already did thee same thing in the code which is given in the question. because their is a class "StoreAddress" used in tag and it is simple.

the problem was to to fetch the data items which i have mentioned in the bullet-list  ...(Store Phone , - Pharmacy Phone , - Open Hours , - Pharmacy Hours,Pickup Options, At this store/location, Site to Store Hours )....   

can you please show me the similar code to do that.

Comment: i want to do same kind of scraping for alot of other pages................for example: http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_results.do?serviceName=&rx_title=com.wm.www.apps.storelocator.page.serviceLink.title.default&rx_dest=%2Findex.gsp&sfrecords=50&sfsearch_single_line_address=K4B .
Can you help me how to do that?  so that i can repeat the same process for rest of the stores... Thanks

Comment: Actually if you look at the source everything is in nice javascript variables for you, it's probably easier to parse those out.

Comment: You are right that it is easy, actually i was talking about other problem that i can't parse other data items in the table, because these are in the <td> tag with same class, can you please show me only for one of these. (for example: to parse Pharmacy Hours , Pickup Options, at this location in 3 separate variables) I tried but failed to do that. I will really appreciate if you just help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Like I say, it can be done in php but it's too painful for me to do it for you. You should really be using python or ruby for this.

Answer (score 1):

i see that they implement a nice hr tag before the adress.
explode it on the hr tag and use the remaining partwith the adress to rebuild the html object.
then iterate through the divs and use preg_match to see if the object contains any reference to your wanted data.

```
foreach($html->find(’div’) as $test)
    {
     if(preg_match(’/Adress/’,$test->innertext))
        {
        filter out addy
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, do you know how to use explode? just get the second piece of the array after exploding. then tebuild the html object with that remainder.

Answer (score 1):

try out [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library. 
On the page there are straight-forward examples that will get you up to speed.

I have been using that successfully for exactly the kind of things you are trying to do.

Comment: yes Siim you are right , but i've already done same kind of work before, at this time i've a specific question related to <td> tags which have neither id nor specific class to recognize. so i can't get the variables like (phone number, at this location, pickup options etc)

Comment: @wqs you could just loop through all <td>s. Use regex pattern to decide what is the type of content (location, time or ...). 
Instead of regex just checking for fixed titles like 'Store Hours' could work as well, as you know then what is the data in following fields.