# Parsing HTML table from a website to array

Tags: php, html, dom

I wanted to parse html tables from a website http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_engineering_college_rankings

basically I want to parse two conetnt in a table **location** and **university**

so I have researched on it and come to know about `DOMDocument();`
and I have also seen many question answers on stackoverflow.

[Parsing specific data items from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762051/parsing-specific-data-items-from-website)

[PHP DOMDocument getElementsByTagname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845908/php-domdocument-getelementsbytagname?rq=1)

I am not sure if I am going in a wrong way so I am here to ask you.

I want to parse two content **location** and **university** which is in the table from this wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_engineering_college_rankings.

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: i want to parse two content **location** and **university** which is in the table from this wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_engineering_college_rankings

Answer (score 0):

Please see the details [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), this is the library which will helps you to crawl the page and get necessary information from the respective page.

Hope it may helps you.

Comment: Hi alankar yes i have also seen it but i want to parse specific content lies in the table 'tr' content ot location and university only

Comment: Yes you can find the respective tr from the table and you can get the text of it. can you please tell me what code you want from wiki pedia url that you have sent ?

Comment: i want to parse two content location and university which is in the table from this wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_engineering_college_rankings